# Android bitmap usage; does double variable bitmap instances pile up in memory cache?

Tags: android, caching, memory, bitmap

When a new bitmap variable is created to have the same value as an original bitmap variable, does it build a copy thereby taking memory cache space for two bitmaps or it only returns the original bitmap cache whenever it is called within the app?

An illustration is this;

```
public static Bitmap originalBmp;
public static Bitmap copyBmp;

originalBmp = ......;
copyBmp = originalBmp;
```

My question now is this; 
in the memory cache, if originalBmp takes 2MB, does calling `copyBmp = originalBmp;` result in a total cache memory of 4MB or it maintains 2MB wherever yet copyBmp is called....just to know that there is no memory pile up with new bitmap variables taking values from originalBmp.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `originalBmp` and `copyBmp` point to objects. We often say they "are" objects, but that is a bit of verbal shorthand.

In your case, when you execute `copyBmp = originalBmp;`, both `originalBmp` and `copyBmp` will point to the same `Bitmap` object, not each to its own copy of that object. So, your 2MB `Bitmap` still consumes only 2MB, despite two fields pointing to it.

Note, though, that putting a 2MB `Bitmap` into a `static` field is dangerous. `static` fields are "intentional memory leaks". That 2MB cannot be freed up for use by other objects until all references to the `Bitmap` are gone. In your case, both `originalBmp` and `copyBmp` are `static`, so they will always point to your 2MB `Bitmap`, until you reset both of those fields to `null` (or point them to some other `Bitmap`). Be very careful when using `static` fields that you do not wind up consuming too much memory.